# Returning the LAST() value in measurement for each tag

Tags: influxdb

I am using influxDB to store weather data at different locations. Temperature and wind are fields and the locations is in a tag. Measurements are taken every minute or so.

```
1: INSERT measurement,location=new-york temp=32.1 wind=3.0  2016-11-26T00:00:00Z
2: INSERT measurement,location=seattle  temp=42.0 wind=3.1  2016-11-26T00:00:53Z
3: INSERT measurement,location=new-york temp=33.1 wind=1.2  2016-11-26T00:01:00Z
4: INSERT measurement,location=seattle  temp=43.0 wind=2.0  2016-11-26T00:01:53Z
```

I would like a query to return the most recent weather data for each location. The result of this query should be ROWS 3 and 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

`select location,last(temp) from measurement group by location`